# bootstrap off canvas menu reveal smaller then 992px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the best plugin I've seen yet for an [off canvas bootstrap menu](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/components/#navmenu).  I'm trying to expose (reveal) the menu if the width of a screen is greater then 992px.

I'm trying to replicate my current navigation being used on my site. Try resizing the browser and the navigation menu gets collapsed at smaller resolutions. This is done via some javascript as seen below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var n, t;
    desktop ? (n = $(".sidebar .wrapper").height(), t = $(document).height(), $(".content").css("min-height", n), $(".sidebar").css("min-height", t + 200)) : (n = $(".sidebar .wrapper").height(), t = $(document).height(), $(".content").css("min-height", n), $(".sidebar").css("min-height", t + 200)), $(".toggle-sidebar").click(function () {
        $("body").toggleClass("show-sidebar")
    });
});
```

Any idea how I can achieve this same effect with the off canvas plugin from jasny?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is supported by Jasny Bootstrap as show in [this example](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu/).

Simply use `offcanvas-sm` instead of `offcanvas`.

```
<div class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas-sm">
   ...
</div>
```

---

For the record, the offcanvas plugin is very flexible. It works on any element hidden by `display: none` and ignores any element that isn't hidden. You can use `@media` to hide the element at any viewport width you like.